# having trouble breaking a youtube embed code up into variables

Tags: php, youtube

I'm trying to take the basic youtube embed code and bbreak it up into variables of height width and url but the code im using keeps throwing a error.

```
<?php
$width = "10";
$height = "20";
$vid url = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/HjgSmoilwV4";

echo '<iframe width="'$width'" height="'$height'" src="'$vid'" frameborder="0"allowfullscreen></iframe>';
?>
```

using this code im getting the following error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in D:\webdesign\webserver\root\dynapage\scripts\admin\add_video.php on line 4

What am I doing wrong? I've Googled and found stuff on escaping but not sure what it expects me to escape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line 4 $vid url , can't have that space there, it's a syntax error.
so change it to:

```
$vid = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/HjgSmoilwV4";
```

and that last line should be:

```
echo "<iframe width='".$width."' height='".$height."' src='".$vid."' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
```

Comment: i dont know what happened with that url i either didnt kow or didnt see it also thanks for your help i can see now how i go about this +1 rep

Comment: @vdbuilder Psh, he had already accepted mine.  Oh well, you need the rep more than I do :)

Answer (score 3):

**In order to use variables inside of strings, you need to use double quotes in PHP.**  So the following:

```
echo '<iframe width="'$width'" height="'$height'" src="'$vid_url'" frameborder="0"allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

should be:

```
echo "<iframe width='$width' height='$height' src='$vid_url' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
```

You are getting a syntax error because you used single quotes and then ended them but still have text after it. Your example code could also be written using the concatenation operator `.`:

```
echo '<iframe width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height . '" src="' . $vid_url . '" frameborder="0"allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

Comment: i just tryed that and its still throwing the same error also isnt it now treating my variables as text and not php cause the code highlighter greys it out the same as the rest of the link

Comment: @user1121999 It's because I used `$vid` instead of `$vid_url`.  That's what you did in your example.  I edited my answer.  Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$width = '10';
$height = '20';
$vid_url = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/HjgSmoilwV4';

echo "<iframe width=\"$width\" height=\"$height\" src=\"$vid_url\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

?>
```

Use of double-quote (") in PHP allows you to embed variable contents by name, as the scripting engine parses double-quoted strings for known patterns. I replaced the single quotes with double quotes and then escaped all of the double quotes.

The main problem with your code sample was that variables cannot include spaces, so I replaced your space with an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply concatenate strings with variables by placing them next to each other on the source input file. Instead, use a `.` to concatenate the values:

```
$ php
<?php
echo 'one' 'two';
?>
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in - on line 2
$ php
<?php
echo 'one' . 'two';
?>
onetwo$
```

Answer (score 0):

The only missing concatenate =]

```
<?php
    $width = "10";
    $height = "20";
    $vid url = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/HjgSmoilwV4";

    echo '<iframe width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" src="'.$vid.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
?>
```

**Useful link**

- [String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)